# Four-indexed infinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, matrix-calculus

I've found on an ancient book a structure of the kind described below and I do not even know if it is a commonly known structure nowadays. For me it doesn't match neither a direct sum nor a direct product.

Can someone tell me something about this? (available references will be appreciate)

The complex vector space of functions defined by the following base $\{\alpha_{ij}\}= \{ \eta_i \tau_j\}$ where $\{\eta_i\}$ and $\{\tau_j\}$ are respectively ortonormal bases of trigonometric polynomials. An element $\overrightarrow{v}$ of this space will be of the form: $\overrightarrow{v} = \sum_{i,j=1}^\infty \alpha_{ij}\eta_i\tau_j$. A linear operator (matrix) over this space will be an infinite dimensional matrix with four indexes which I'm not sure if has anything to do with tensors.

Answer (score 1):

If you require $\sum_{i,j} |\alpha_{ij}|^2 < \infty$, the vector space is the [Hilbert space tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_Hilbert_spaces) $\mathcal H = \mathcal H_\eta \otimes \mathcal H_\tau$ of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H_\eta$ generated by the
$\eta_i$ and $\mathcal H_\tau$ generated by the $\tau_j$.

Comment: Hello Robert. Yes, the condition you point out is required and, yes, it is really a tensor product of Hilbert spaces. I'ts wonderful to see how everything match.